# My workspace became out of sync with the repo as I was working. Now, I cannot submit my changes nor can I download the latest from the repo

Tags: plasticscm

I was working on code while our artist was working on his binary files. He had submitted his files to the repo. After that, I tried to submit my updates and got the following error,

> The merge operation is not currently available in the cloud server

I get this message too when I try to download updates so my workspace is in sync.

Help!

Comment: I'm using Plastic Cloud, and merging is not currently supported on the server. How do I merge with my local repo first and then push out the merged files to the server?

Answer (score 0):

As "https://www.plasticscm.com/cloud/index.html" states developers should use distributed servers in order to be able to merge. Artists are fine with Gluon. Notice that if all your development is done at br:/main then developers can also use gluon.

From the message you are getting it seems you are directly working with the cloud repo instead of your local one. Merge in the Plastic SCM Cloud is not supported yet, it will be available in a near future.

Now, you should create a local repository, pull the cloud content into your local server and start working, once you are done with your local changes you can push the new changesets to the Plastic SCM Cloud repository.

The Sync view will help you a lot with this process of pulling/pushing information: [More info](http://blog.plasticscm.com/2011/08/this-is-how-i-use-synch-view.html). This is how your workflow should be:

[image]

As you are currently having local changes that can't be submitted because the merge lock I do recommend you first to backup the changed files and then start working distributed, restore the files in your workspace and you will be able to checkin and then push back to the Cloud repository.